# Nexus opens same app twice when using custom URL to launch the app

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, nexus-s

My app has the feature of being launched from the browser if the user clicks on a particular type of URL. This thing works well on any android phones except the Google Nexus having ICS. With Nexus, when I click on a URL which can open my app, the app opens properly, but if i go to home screen and click on the app icon, even that opens up. So now I can see my app opened in the browser app as well as my own app, simultaneously. I saw the same behavior with other apps too. like the play store or twitter.
Wondering if this is okay or can cause some issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be considered indifferent, neither OK nor bad - however, you could always make use of the `Activity` available via the `AndroidManifest.xml` so that you only keep one instance of the given `Activity` available.

Parameters on the `<activity />` level in the manifest:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
<!-- OR -->
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Comment: yeah this could work. il check n get back here. thanks for that :)